# Wait javascript in webview is finished to continue Android Java

Tags: java, android, multithreading, webview, countdowntimer

I'm new to learning java. I have been working how i can do it for 2 days. I will be mad. Please help me

I want that when my function run, all activity must wait until my function is finished.

an example

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    Log.v("htmlg","oncreate started");

    main_command();
    /*
    *
    *  main_command(), When this command run application must wait in here.
    *
    * */

    Log.v("htmlg", "oncreate finished");

}
```

public static int finished = 0;

```
public void main_command(){

    /*
    * 
    * There is some webview actions in here. it takes about 5 minutes. 
    * 
    * When webview operations are finished.
    * I call javascript command javascript:window.HTMLOUT.ok(); 
    * I want everything wait until webview operations are finished and javascript command runned. 
    * 
    * */

}
```

But I could not do it with no way.  When main_command() runned, Log.v() function will run after it immediately. but main_command() is still running and it is not finished. when it finished a javascript command will call a function inside android. then process will be finished and application can continue to work where it was.

Now, I'm telling my experiences.

- I tried to write webview codes inside Asynctask but I could not use webview inside asynctask.
- i put webview inside rununithread() inside asynctask, i could not do again.
- i tried to put main_command() inside CountdownTimer but "oncreate finished"  line runned before CountdownTimer finished.

Now i feel helpless. I dont know java or android programming so much. I am php programmer. I try to do webview application. I dont understand java structure so much. If you can do , can you write correct example working code ? Because I dont understand all examples. I looked and read everything maybe there was solution but I could not understand it. I need your help.

Thanks

Comment: you want to stop your ui or your code running?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to block the main thread, otherwise the android system will show "Application not responding" error. And your users will most probably choose to kill the app.

From what I understand, you want your application to resume when you call it through a javascript command. This is how you can proceed:

1. Make a function `postMainCommand()`. In this method, write everything that needs to be executed after that javascript command call. I mean the ones like:

   ```
   Log.v("htmlg", "oncreate finished");
   ```

   Call this method after your web-work is complete.
2. Till your job is in progress, you can show a non-cancelable progress-dialog with some text like "Please wait...". Or, if you can keep track of the progress, you can keep updating the message:

   ```
   ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
   dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
   dialog.setCancelable(false);
   dialog.show();
   ```

   Non-cancellable because you don't want the user to interact with the app in-between, right?
3. When your webview job is over, call `dialog.cancel();`